# Worklight 6.2 - Broadcast notification not being sent

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

We are trying to run the sample app for push notifications with some modification to get it to send out a broadcast notification, but it is not getting sent.

We have modified the PushBackendEmulator code as well. The emulator invokes the submitBroadCastNotification procedure successfully and the following result is returned:

> Server response :: /*-secure-{"result":"Notification sent to all
>   users","isSuccessful":true}*/

However, it appears the `WL.Server.sendMessage` method is not sending the message and returns. I am not able to see the server side logs either after a thorough search on the liberty server except for the messages.log on the liberty server which shows the following when `WL.Server.sendMessage` is called.

> ht.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation E
>   FWLSE0227E: Failed to send notification. Reason: FPWSE0009E: Internal
>   server error. No devices found [project worklight]

Here is the adapter code:

```
function submitBroadcastNotification( notificationText) {

    var notification = {};
    notification.message = {};
    notification.message.alert = notificationText;

    //notification.target = {};
    //notification.target.tagNames = ['test'];


    WL.Logger.debug("broadcast: " + notification.message.alert );

    var delayTimeOut = **WL.Server.sendMessage**("PushNotificationsApp", notification);
    WL.Logger.debug("Return value from WL.Server.sendMessage :"+ delayTimeOut);

    return {
    result : "Notification sent to all users"
    };
}
```

Here is the PushBackendEmulator code:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
        String serverUrl =
                "http://208.124.245.78:9080/worklight";

        String notificationText = "Hellofrombroadcastingnotifications";
        String userId = "admin";

        notificationText = notificationText.replace(" ", "%20");
        Logger.debug("sending broadcast notification: " + notificationText);

        URL url = new URL(serverUrl
                + "/invoke?

    adapter=PushAdapter&procedure=submitBroadcastNotification&parameters=['" + userId + "','" + notificationText + "']");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
        Logger.debug("Connected to server");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String response = "";
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            response+= inputLine;
        Logger.debug("response is:"+ response);
        in.close();

        Logger.debug("Server response :: " + response);

        connection.disconnect();
```

Comment: Does it work if you invoke the adapter from Worklight Studio instead of using a modified version of the pushbackend .jar file?

Comment: Also keep it in mind that the pushbackend is only an emulation and should not be used in any other capacity.

Comment: Was the app launched on the device atleast once? If you have access to database, can you check if there are entries in push_devices table for the app "PushNotificationsApp"?

Comment: Idan, you mean running on the localhost? yes it does but in this case we are trying to run this on remote worklight server. The curious thing is the WL.Server.sendMessage is returning and the subsequent result message is obtained but the message does not reach the client.

Comment: @Srujanreddy, can you provide an answer (if you have a question - edit yours).

Comment: @idan, we raised PMR for this expecting answer from them.

Comment: @Srujanreddy, what is the PMR number? Why do you think this should be a PMR...? Based on your answer below it sounds like you did not register your device.

Comment: @Idan, PMR no 17514,756,000. I can see the device which is registered in worklight console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your application from the PMR, it seems to me like you have mixed both event source-based notifications and broadcast notifications.

If you want to use Broadcast notifications, this means you **cannot** try imposing sending the notification to any specific userId, etc as it is not needed nor based on userIds.

By default, all devices are auto-subscribed to a tag called "push.ALL".
You can read more about broadcast notifications API methods [in the IBM Worklight Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_send_push_notifications.html).

This is a modified version of your application, tested in iOS and Android:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2yk2pbvykrzfoh/broadcastNotificationsTest.zip?dl=0

Basically, I stripped away from it anything not related to broadcast notifications:

- I removed the push securitytest from application-descriptor.xml
- I removed any function from the adapter XML and JS files and main.js file that is related to event source-based notifications.

The end result is that after the app is loaded, you are right inside the application (no login).
I then right-clicked the adapter folder in Studio > invoke procedure, and selected the submitBroadcastNotification option to send the notification ("aaa").

In the device, a notification was received. Tapping it (if the app is closed) launches the application, which then triggers the `WL.Client.Push.onMessage` API in common\js\main.js to display alerts containing the payload and props of the received notification.

This was tested in both iOS and Android.
As the application was loading, I could see in LogCat and Xcode console the token registration.

- To test this in iOS, you will need to update application-descriptor.xml with your own pushSender password and add your own apns-certificatae-sandbox.p12 file.
- To test in Android, make sure you are have generated a **browser** key in the GCM console and are using it in application-descriptor.xml
- For both, make sure that [all requires ports and addresses](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/#projectSetupAndGuidelines) and accessible in your network

Comment: Hi Idan, Thank you for uploading project. we have tried importing project into new workspace but still we are getting same error (Device not found error) and on mobile I got "unexpected response".

Comment: Go over the training module. Verify you do not have any required ports or addresses block in your network configuration. Start testing the app in the development environment. Provide full log from either Xcode or logcat.

Comment: Thanks idan, Now we are able to send notifications to devices.