# Use persistent cookie to subscribe to an eventsource?

Tags: cookies, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

In this question [Worklight: Push notification without User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542930/worklight-push-notification-without-user-id), the given answer was to subscribe a persistent cookie userID with the event source.. my question is: How can I do this? how can I use the userID given by the cookie ( I already got the userID ) to subscribe to my eventSource? Can't seem to find this anywhere on the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is are additional questions you need to ask yourself, before looking into what you wrote.

Are you using Worklight 6.2 or above?
Are you looking to send generic information (i.e. not sensitive, per-user data (like bank account balance and the like))?

If the answer is 'yes' for both of the above, do not bother yourself with event source-based notifications. Instead, use either broadcast or tag-based notifications (tags = "topics of interest"). Using this approach does not require any additional work on your part other than actually sending the notification.

You can take a look at the documentation:

- Developer Center: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/
- Knowledge Center: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_tag-based_notifications_setting_up.html

In the following answer you can find an example for broadcast notifications (broadcast notification is a form of tag-based notifications): https://stackoverflow.com/a/27881423/1530814

Comment: They are yes for both the above :) I shall look into it thanks!

Comment: @LaravelStudent, Good to hear, please mark as Resolved when you can.